# How to remove last word from a string after a specific character

Tags: php, preg-match

I am wondering how can i remove the last word from a string after a specific character.

These are couple of strings

```
lv_datatable_5_english
lv_datatable_5_arabic

How can i remove "english" and "arabic" from these string to get this

lv_datatable_5_
```

This is what i have tried so far

```
echo implode(" ", array_slice(str_word_count($id, 1), 0, -1));
echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "_"));
```

But this removes the entire words starts from _

and i got this output

> "lv datatable"

Comment: Will the string always have the same amount of `_`?

Comment: yes,Only last word would be changed.@LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways of achieving this. One option is to use `preg_replace` to remove all characters from a set from the end of a string:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^_]+$/', '', 'lv_datatable_5_english');

// lv_datatable_5_
```

The regular expression matches all characters except `_`, and anchors to the end of the string with `$`

If you find it clearer, you can explicitly return a substring of the subject up to and including the last `_` character:

```
$string = 'lv_datatable_5_english';
echo substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '_') + 1);
```